# Calling CPP function from python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, interop, ctypes

I know - there are a billion and a half similar questions. I tried most (even all) of them and none of them helped.

I need to call a **c++ 11** function from python.

```
// test.cpp
#define DLL_PUBLIC extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
DLL_PUBLIC int init_module(void** module, void** error);
```

I'm building SO as following:

```
# Make
gcc -std=c++11 -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC test.cpp
gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

Python code:

```
# test.py
test_lib = CDLL('./libtest.so')
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    test_lib = CDLL('./libtest.so', mode=1 )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
```

I already tried to load clib and stdlib before loading my - doesn't help.
Is there any generic way to specify that my lib needs to load all dependencies on loading? (as in windows dlls?)

Thanks, and sorry for bothering.

Comment: Try `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: @RustyX it is worked... But why?
The problem - that native library is a part of another big project which uses gcc for build, and there is no way to change it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're compiling and linking using the `gcc` command, which defaults to C mode. For C++ mode you should use the `g++` command.

For compiling it's not an issue because GCC detects the `.cpp` extension and switches to C++ mode, but for *linking* you really need to tell GCC to link in C++ mode otherwise it won't link with the C++ runtime library.

NB: `g++` is roughly equivalent to `gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc`. So that might be the solution for you if you really want to use the `gcc` command. More details can be found in the GCC documentation for [compile](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html) and [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) options.